# How to store a value, passed from a method which has an array as parameter and return type of double?

Tags: java, methods, return-type

I have a method which has an array as parameter, I've wanted to pass a double value from it but can't store the value passed from the method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double [] temperature = {2.5, 10.3, 50.0, 66.7, 77.9, 33.2, 0.33};

    double final = averageTemp(temperature);

    System.out.println(final);
}
public static double averageTemp(double [] temp){
    int size =temp.length ;
    double total = 0;
    for(int i =0; i<size; i++){
        total += temp[i];
    }
    double average =  total/size;

    return average;
}
```

I expect to store the returned "average" in "final" variable and print it.
But getting error.

Comment: `final` is a special keyword in java. change variable name.

Comment: Thank you so much, just changed the variable name to "finalAverage". This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

"final" is a keyword in Java.

Pick a different variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
double [] temps = {2.5, 10.3, 50.0, 66.7, 77.9, 33.2, 0.33};

OptionalDouble od = DoubleStream.of(temps).average();

od.ifPresent(average -> {
   System.out.println(average);
});
```

DoubleStream has an average method that calculates the average of the doubles in the array and returns an OptionalDouble. The OptionalDouble is returned in case there is no average to be returned, like, if you send an empty array, you shouldn't return 0 because 0 is still a number. With the OptionalDouble you check if the average is present, and if so, you can get it with `optionalDouble.get();` or the method that I used.

You can use this DoubleStream object inside of your averageTemp method. Change the variable of `double final = ...;` to something like `double average = ...;`